# Constructing views in a non-ui thread and consuming in the ui thread

Tags: android, thread-safety

I'm creating a set of webview objects in a non-UI thread and keep adding them to a queue once the page load of the webview is completed. The UI thread will eventually query for a webview and if there are elements in the maintained queue, it'll be picked from the queue. This non-UI thread will keep running forever and fill the queue as & when required. Unfortunately, when the UI thread renders the webview, though it gets rendered properly, the non-UI thread suddenly fails with the error 'CalledFromWrongThreadException'. I'm not sure whether this behavior is expected. I've created a sample program to demonstrate the same. Can somebody help me identify the problem here?

```
public class MultiThreadTest extends Activity {

    private volatile WebView mWv;
    private LinearLayout mLL;
    private volatile Handler nonUiThreadHandler = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        Button creator = (Button) findViewById(R.id.creator);
        creator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                createThread();
            }
        });

        Button consumer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.consumer);
        consumer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mLL.addView(mWv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));
                mWv.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createThread() {

        Thread t = new Thread (new Runnable() {         
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                nonUiThreadHandler = new Handler();
                Looper.loop();          
            }
        }, "Creator thread");

        t.start();

        while (!t.isAlive() || nonUiThreadHandler==null) {}

        nonUiThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                constructView();
            }
        });
    }

    public void constructView() {
        mWv = new WebView(MultiThreadTest.this);
        mWv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWv.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");
        mWv.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly from when I encountered this exception, Android doesn't like when another thread tries to make changes to the UI. What you need to do is to have your other threads send some message back to the main UI thread (using the Handler) to execute those changes. See this as well: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading

Comment: you could also use `runOnUiThread()`, which does the same but without handlers.

Comment: Yes views must be constructed on the thread they will be shown on.

Comment: @anothem Thanks for pointing out. Yes, I'm aware of that restriction. And that's the precise reason why I'm doing the following lines from the UI thread.             

mLL.addView(mWv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));
mWv.requestFocus();

(continued in the next comment...) (1/2)

Comment: (continued from previous comment...) (2/2)
If you notice, the intention is to create the web view (mWv) in a non-ui thread but eventually use it in the UI thread. The reason for doing this is that, the page I'm trying to load is quite heavy & I don't want this operation to block the other UI operations. Hence, the intention is to wait for the onPageLoadFinished operation on mWv and upon hitting that, consume it in the main thread.

Thanks,

Comment: @hackbod Thanks for the response. Based on the responses received for this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974048/is-it-safe-to-create-and-modify-views-in-a-background-thread-before-adding-them-t) and also by doing some simple experiments, I was able to created & consume views from non-UI threads on a UI thread.  (1/2)

Comment: @hackbod But there seems to be some specific issue, when the non-UI thread that creates the view remains alive when the UI thread tries displaying the same. I mean, the invalidate operation on the created view seems to land up on the non-UI thread's queue for some weird reason (may be something to do with the handlers set when creating the thread?). (2/2)